# Don't display not present date values

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to get Highcharts to display the daily usage statistics for e.g. a company's ressource. The opening days of the company are from monday to friday.

My dataseries look like this:

```
[Date.UTC(2012, 8, 6),17.5], (Thu)
[Date.UTC(2012, 8, 7),42.5], (Fri)
-- weekend
[Date.UTC(2012, 8, 10),20],  (Mon)
[Date.UTC(2012, 8, 11),20],  (Tue)
[Date.UTC(2012, 8, 12),40],  (Wed)
[Date.UTC(2012, 8, 13),30],  (Thu)
...
```

In the time series chart there are inserted two labels for the missing two weekend-dates (2012, 8, 8 and 2012, 8, 9), but I don't want those labels to be displayed because there are no values for these labels and so the adjacent dates will be connected via a line but this is wrong.

Is it possible to turn off this 'date interpolation' and show only the values I've inserted?

Thanks with regards, Phil

Comment: You can insert null values for the weekend points and highcharts will show the chart as discontinous

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'd like to display a continuous graph...

Comment: Can you give a jsFiddle as to what is happening and what is your expectation?

Comment: Hi, in this jsFiddle you can see that there is a spline-interpolation e.g. between 12.Jan and 27.Jan but i don't wanna have the interpolated days in between (13,14,...,25,26): http://jsfiddle.net/Xqm7R/

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible using a scatter series and customizing the tickPositioner callback for the x-axis and filtering of x series data (dates) thats not a weekday.

I've created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/hkskoglund/6jNGg/

To allow for missing weekends days **null** should be pushed for the y-value in the series data (as mentioned in comment above)

Another option without using a datetime axis is to use a category axis where you push the dates in the series you have data for. This will allow to have a continous plot. Take a look at the new fiddle: [Areaspline with categories as dates](http://jsfiddle.net/hkskoglund/fsUqY/)

```
xAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    // http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat()
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b', this.value);
                }
            },
            categories : [            
                Date.UTC(2012, 8, 6),Date.UTC(2012, 8, 7),
                Date.UTC(2012, 8, 10),Date.UTC(2012, 8, 11),
                Date.UTC(2012, 8, 11)]
       },

        series: [{
            name : 'resources',
            data: [17.5,42.5,20,25,20]

        }]
```

As far as I can understand using datetime on the x-axis using your requested plot-configuration is not possible without changing the source/rendering of Highcharts series. It seems like discontinuties with null values is separated into socalled *segments*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the datetime-axis feature is great, also in combination with the zoom feature, so I think I have to take another graph-type like the scatter series :-(

Comment: You can choose what type of graph you want. I've updated the fiddle to only show labels for working-days with zooming and type = 'area'? Is this more what you was looking for? Also based on info from http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-missing

Comment: Thanks Henning - not directly - I'd like to put them together like: http://www.pictureupload.de/originals/pictures/250213093825_DateSeries.jpg

Comment: Check updated answer, it allows for stiching values together continously

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. Unfortunately there is a larger gap between the labels of the 11th and the 13th. Seems legit because there is one day in between missing - but this is the behaviour I don't wanna have and I think there is no way to turn off this "interpolation"...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set oridinal as false?

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for the hint. Unfortunately setting ordinal to false doesn't work at all. ...but this would be exactly that what I want to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but did you try formatting your dates as Strings before inserting them?  If so, you can then use a category axis.  This should work as long as you don't have any entry for date vs having a null.

I use Highcharts embedded in JasperReports, but this allows us to get your desired behavior.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for your reply but unfortunately I don't have the chance to test it any more :-(